# Connection through another website - Wordpress -> APS

Tags: wordpress, forms, authentication, post, asp-classic

I've got a question. I have actually 2 websites.
One for the front, one for the data-base products.

I need to connect clients thru the first website (Wordpress), and then, send information to the second, and they are automatically connect.

I can create a form POST on Wordpress, for send infos, but I always have error of connection.
I have also try to use  or  but not really work...

Also find by me to show the all website in my first website

Here my redirect form :
[https://pro.mag-online.com/hd/main.asp?LOGIN=[field](https://pro.mag-online.com/hd/main.asp?LOGIN=%5Bfield) id="LOGIN"]&PWD=[field id="PWD"]

Here the code of the normal login page

```
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>MAG CONNECTION : First European Purchasing Group for American bikes</TITLE><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" /><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2">history.forward()</SCRIPT><SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript1.2" src="mag.js"></SCRIPT><link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/iconehd.ico"></HEAD><BODY bgcolor="#FFFFFF" text="#000000">

<LINK href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><br />
      <br /> 
<FORM NAME="Login" ACTION="main.asp" METHOD="POST">
  <center>
    <font size="6" face="Arial">Verbinding</font> 
    <p> 
    <br>
    <table width="39%" border="0">
      <tr> 
        <td width="14%"><div align="right">
          Gebruiker 
          : </div></td>
        <td width="11%"><input type="TEXT" name="LOGIN" value="" class="input2"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td width="14%"><div align="right">
          Password 
          : </div></td>
        <td width="11%"><input type="PASSWORD"  name="PWD" value="" class="input2"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p><br>
      <input type="SUBMIT" name="BTOK" value="Bevestigen"  class="input3">
    </p>
    <p>&nbsp; </p>
    <p>
      U bent een dealer en niet geregistreerd, bel:
      <strong>Tel: (+33) 0820 820 111</strong><br />
    Pour devenir membre de notre groupement d'achat : <a href="http://www.mag-connection.com/html/form_regis.htm">cliquez ici </a></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </center>
</FORM>
<script language="JavaScript">
document.Login.LOGIN.focus()
</script>
</body></html>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `I always have error of connection` - what the error says ? and what info you send, and how ? - what do you mean connection ? maybe you mean logged in ?

Comment: Hello Aristos. Yes exaclty, I'm using Login & PWD to logged in, by a POST method form 


Error message : 
ADODB.Recordset erreur '800a0cc1'

/hd/connmain.mag, ligne 92

Comment: I hope you realize that with out code no one can help you - this error is when you run a wrong sql command - and not find the records you ask for - also this is probably asp classic not asp.net

Comment: You are right, I have add some infos on my post...

Comment: I have to say passing login and password in clear text over an HTTP GET request is a massive security risk and will likely end with your customer database being compromised. Strongly recommend you cease trying to solve your problem this way.